# Usage example of as2crypto

Tags: encryption, actionscript-2

I've got an AS3 project that I've successfully added encryption to with the excellent [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) library.  I've also got an AS2 project that I would like to add the exact same encryption to, with [the AS2 version of as3crypto](http://www.yuniti.com/As2RSA).

Unfortunately, AS2 doesn't have the excellent `ByteArray` class, so it hasn't been as easy to get working.

My basic process is this: Open a `Socket` connection, create an ARC4 object, encrypt data with the ARC4 instance before sending, decrypt incoming data with an ARC4 object when receiving.  Straightforward.

In AS3 this is working great.  How do I do the same thing in AS2?  Is there an example of usage of the AS2 RSA library somewhere that I haven't been able to find?  Anyone have any idea of how the ARC4 class is supposed to be used in AS2?

Comment: What's so great about a crypto package that hasn't been updated since 2008? It looks like studentware to me. Competent studentware for sure, but who is checking the security and maintaining the software?

Comment: It's freely available, and it works.  The code base is not difficult to understand, and comes in both AS3 and AS2 flavours.  All those point together make it stand way over all the other options I've seen.

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears that instead of byte arrays the library just uses arrays of numbers 0 to 255.  Does just converting what would have been a `ByteArray` to that format not work?

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples:

- [Flash Hacks](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596006457/)
- [ActionScript Cookbook](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596004903/)
- [Protect and Obfuscate your Flash files](http://etutorials.org/Macromedia/Flash+hacks.+100+industrial-strength+tips+tools/Chapter+12.+Security/Hack+98+Protect+and+Obfuscate+Your+Flash+Files/)